# Why are CCD cameras still used, not CMOS for live view from the rocket?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, camera

I watched the start of the CRS-13 and the view of the engine and other elements of the rocket are shown from CCD cameras in sd. The resolution ok, does not have to be large but why is it still used for this color-washed and susceptible to vertical smear cameras of the old generation and not CMOS? From what you can now observe, CMOS provides a better picture and no CCD flaws.

At old NASA launches video feed was analog (CCD output = analog), spaceX uses digital transmission so what is the matter with these old technology cameras?

In picture characteristic for ccd overexposed pixels vertical smear lines

[image: characteristic for ccd overexposed pixel vertical smear line]

Comment: You do know that CMOS image sensors are an *older* technology than CCD, right?

Answer (score 7):

CCDs aren't actually analog, they are a type of digital camera. There are a number of them out there, but the two most popular methods of manufacturing a digital camera are CCD and CMOS. CCD cameras have a higher ratio of sensor to space ratio, and thus tend to be a bit better at low light, but at the cost of being more expensive. In many other areas, CMOS will perform better, however.

In the end, I suspect they want the better low light performance, and thus went with a CCD. But both can be good sensors.

http://www.teledynedalsa.com/imaging/knowledge-center/appnotes/ccd-vs-cmos/

Answer (score 1):

In the latest launch (Bangabandhu Satellite-1 Mission),it looks like they are now using CMOS. Lots of rolling shutter during high vibration moments, lack of vertical smearing in strong highlights and purple tint on the engine glow during second burn of second stage.

Comment: Is there a web site where you could get specs on the camera?